# change global GNU readline history location

Tags: command-history, readline

I was able to change the history location of some tools via envvars, e.g.:

```
export PYTHONHISTFILE=/tmp/.python_history
export NODE_REPL_HISTORY=/tmp/.node_repl_history
export REDISCLI_HISTFILE=/tmp/.rediscli_history
export USQL_HISTORY=/tmp/.usql_history
export SDCV_HISTFILE=/tmp/.sdcv_history
export SQLITE_HISTORY=/tmp/.sqlite_history
```

However, there are some tools that do not have any options for that, so i am looking for a library-level option to move all the history files in a path different from `$HOME`.